# Comparing rowset data in Java

Tags: java

I get two cached row sets of data from two tables; table1 and table2.

table1

```
OrgCode Name    Amt FeeCode
1       John    100 R
1       Micheal 200 L
```

table2

```
OrgCode AgreementNo AddressNo   CustomerNo  FeeCode
1          111        211         555   R
1          222        212         666   L
1          333        213         777   P
```

I need to compare two cachedrow sets, and send the data (cached row set) table to JSP depending on the  matching feecode in tables2.

The Sql formed for Cached row set for table-1 is dynamically formed,the same method is used by different classes,with return type cached row set

How might I do this?

Comment: Why not having them compared at the database level? It would be more efficient ;)

Comment: Can you not use sql join?

Comment: The Sql for Cached row set for table-1 is dynamically formed,the same method is used by diffeerent classes,with return type cached row set :(